# Resolution method: example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Now i study resolution method over first order logic in university but i can't feel power of this method.

Can anyone give such statement that would be at least some nontrivial and interesting and at the same time i can prove it with resolution method.

(If resolution method prove statement but it requires computer for evaluating, it's ok for me. More interesting question for me - what most interesting statement can prove resolution method, may be with computer).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolution gets used a fair amount in automated reasoning.  This [paper](http://www.automatedreasoning.net/docs_and_pdfs/equivcalc_expeditions.pdf) gives you an example.